# How to extract without creating recursive folders

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, unzip

I've not been able to extract a recursively encoded zip file into a flat target directory using VBS on Windows 7. Here's the core part of the zip extraction code:

objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions

Where intOptions is given the value of 4096, from this list of values:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_zip.php#CopyHereUNZIP

So where the files in the zip are normally extracted to one or more subfolders (instead of the selected folder), the files extract to those subfolders. I don't have to worry about files "clobbering" each other, since there's only a couple of uniquely named files.

Other values for intOptions seem to work correctly, such as 512, which does "not confirm the creation of a new directory if the operation requires one to be created."

Any ideas?

*** Edit: full working script below, as requested, using Ansgar's Answer ***

```
Dim strCurrentFolder, ExtractTo, strCurrentZip, src, dst, fso, strFileName, app

strCurrentFolder = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName,WScript.ScriptName,"") ' Path where script is running
ExtractTo = strCurrentFolder & "temp1"
WScript.Echo ExtractTo
strFileName = "samplefile.zip"



'If the extraction location does not exist create it.
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If NOT fso.FolderExists(ExtractTo) Then
   fso.CreateFolder(ExtractTo)
End If

'Unzip "C:\path\to\your.zip", "C:\output\folder"
Unzip strCurrentZip, ExtractTo

WScript.Quit



Sub Unzip(src, dst)
' Function to extract all files from a compressed "folder"
' (ZIP, CAB, etc.) using the Shell Folders' CopyHere method
Dim obj, app, intOptions
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")


' Loop through zipped "subfolders"
' http://stackoverflow.com/a/24515198/1569434
  For Each obj In app.NameSpace(src).Items
      If obj.IsFolder Then
     'WScript.Echo "Recursing into nested folders..."
     Unzip obj.Path, dst              'recurse into nested folders
    Else
     'WScript.Echo "Extracting files"
     app.NameSpace(dst).CopyHere obj 'extract files, not using intOptions right now
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between files and folders. Extract files, and recurse into the nested folders, e.g. like this:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Sub Unzip(src, dst)
  For Each obj In app.NameSpace(src).Items
    If obj.IsFolder Then
      Unzip obj.Path, dst              'recurse into nested folders
    Else
      app.NameSpace(dst).CopyHere obj  'extract files
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Unzip "C:\path\to\your.zip", "C:\output\folder"
```

Comment: you're a *lifesaver*! I made a slight mod to your script to get it to work, and edited your answer. If you'd prefer I create my own answer from yours, or if I got it wrong, pls let me know, but this slight edit works perfectly and I wanted to assign yours as the answer that worked for me. You're a savior! :-D

Comment: @Lizz: Your modification shouldn't make a difference (and didn't when I tested it). Also, it's a waste of resources to create a new `Shell.Application` object with every recursion. One global object should suffice. What was the error you said you were getting before?

Comment: When "Set app..." is moved outside Sub or commented, I get err "Object required: 'app'" w/Code 800A01A8. Where did I go wrong? :(

Comment: @Lizz: It should work with a global variable `app`, e.g. by making `Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")` the first line in your script (or the second line if you use `Option Explicit`). If you still get the error after that: please show your complete, unaltered script (edit your question and paste it there).

Comment: Suggested global variable on 1st line didn't work. Code in Question is fully working; simply move line "Set app =..." to top to get same err msg mentioned above.

Comment: @Lizz: That's because you have a `Dim app` inside the procedure. That creates a new local variable `app`, which remains empty when you don't initialize it. Move the line `Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")` to the top of the script and change `Dim obj, app, intOptions` to `Dim obj, intOptions` and the code will work as expected. On a different note, since you already `Dim` all your variables, you should also add `Option Explicit` as the first line of your script.

Comment: Perfect! :-D I should reverse the edit I made to your answer, right. And *thank you*!!!

Comment: @Lizz: You're welcome. No need to reverse the edit, I already rolled it back.